# How to handle popup in IE using watir-classic

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-classic

I'm trying to click on close but it is not clicking.

below is my code:

```
b.button(:class , "close").click
```

HTML code:

```
 <div class="modal-content alert-">
<div class="modal-body">
<button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
<span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
<span class="sr-only">Close</span>
</button>
<div>
<h4 id="daModal1493381568370"/>
</div>
<br/>
<p>Invalid driving experience, please call us at 666 55555 for assistance</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Note: First i'm trying to check alert exists or not then clicking on close.

```
b.alert.exists?# i'm getting false
b.button(:class , "close").click
```

And also tried:

```
b.span(:class , "sr-only").click
```

Comment: What's `b`? How did you get it?

Comment: Is there an exception or does the click just do nothing? Have you verified that you are clicking the right close button - ie its possible that there are multiple elements with that class. Make sure there is only one - `p b.buttons(:class, "close").count`

Comment: Note that `b.alert` checks for an actual JavaScript alert dialog. Yours appears to be just regular HTML elements that look like a dialog.

Comment: @Surya b is Browser object. (b=Watir::Browser.new)